# convert mysql to query to laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Hello i am trying to convert this mysql query to laravel query but still i have no success. can you please help to convert this mysql query to laravel query.

Mysql query as below

```
select *,SUM(pp.starting_balance) as total from (select `aa`.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(cc.purchasedescription," (",bb.quantity,")") SEPARATOR " , ") as bundle_item 
from `composite_inventories` as aa 
left join 
`composite_has_inventories` as bb on `aa`.`id` = `bb`.`composite_inventory_id` 
left join 
`inventories` as cc on `bb`.`inventory_id` = `cc`.`id` 
where 
`aa`.`subscriber_id` = '2'
group by 
`aa`.`id`) as tt left join `composite_has_warehouses` as pp on `tt`.`id` = `pp`.`composite_inventory_id` group by pp.composite_inventory_id
```

I tried to build as below but not working

```
$row = DB::table('composite_inventories')->select('composite_inventories.*',
            DB::raw('SUM(composite_has_warehouses.starting_balance) as total')
            DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(inventories.purchasedescription," (",composite_has_inventories.quantity,")") SEPARATOR " , ") as bundle_item')
            )
            ->leftJoin('composite_has_inventories', 'composite_inventories.id', '=', 'composite_has_inventories.composite_inventory_id')
            ->leftJoin('inventories', function($join) {
                $join->on('composite_has_inventories.inventory_id', '=', 'inventories.id');
            })

            ->where('composite_inventories.subscriber_id',$subscriber_id)
            ->groupBy('composite_inventories.id')
            ->leftJoin('composite_has_warehouses', 'composite_inventories.id', '=', 'composite_has_warehouses.composite_inventory_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: show the code you have tried.

Comment: What have you tried? Anyway - with complex queries like this, using the raw SQL is often more readable than using Laravel's query builder. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries

Comment: i have posted the query which i tried in laravel

Comment: what exactly you mean by not working? Any errors or output not as expected

Comment: i am not able to getting same result as mysql query in my laravel query. in mysql query it returns correct value for bundle items but in laravel query it returns wrong value for bundle items

Comment: is my query posssible in laravel query not raw queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DB::select()` method and place your raw query as a string:

```
DB::select("select *,SUM(pp.starting_balance) as total from (select `aa`.*,
DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(cc.purchasedescription,' (',bb.quantity,')') SEPARATOR ' , ') as bundle_item ')
from `composite_inventories` as aa 
left join 
`composite_has_inventories` as bb on `aa`.`id` = `bb`.`composite_inventory_id` 
left join 
`inventories` as cc on `bb`.`inventory_id` = `cc`.`id` 
where 
`aa`.`subscriber_id` = '2'
group by 
`aa`.`id`) as tt left join `composite_has_warehouses` as pp on `tt`.`id` = `pp`.`composite_inventory_id` group by pp.composite_inventory_id");
```

Comment: ok i can use raw query but i have where condition is dynamic on this query. if status is set then my query will have status in where condition.

Comment: You can include this as a where condition like the following:

and IF('" . $condition . "' = some_value, put where clause condition here', 1)

This will ensure that if the condition is met, then the condition is added to the query else return 1 (true) which won't affect your query.

Let me know if this helps